# Time Complexity on triple Nested For loops where indexes are dependent on each other

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, time, complexity-theory

I have this c++ like pseudo code here:

```
 for ( i = 1; i ≤ (n – 2); i++)
     for (j = i + 1; j ≤ (n – 1); j ++)
         for (k = j + 1; k ≤ n; k++)
             Print “Hello World”;
```

I am fairly certain the time complexity of this particular block of code is O(n^3) because it is triple nested for loop and they are all going to at minimum n - 2 so I generalized (n-2) * (n-1) * n

But I have been trying to solve the actual time complexity function. This is how far I got and could not proceed any further:

summation from i = 1 to n-2, summation from j = (i+1) to n-1, summation from k = (j+1) to n.

I understand that the inner most loop performs n - (j+1) steps, the middle loop performs (n-1)-(i+1) steps, and the outer loop performs (n-2)-i steps. I just need some pointers on how to simplify the summations to come to a time complexity function.

Thank you!

Comment: C(n,3), since this enumerates the ways of choosing three distinct numbers from the range [1,n].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If interested, the loops iterate through every combination of n things taken 3 at a time, starting with (1,2,3), (1,2,4), ... , and ending with (n-2,n-1,n), which is n! / (( 3! )( (n-3)!) ) = (n)(n-1)(n-2)/6 = (n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n) / 6 , which leads to O(n^3).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I was tackling this problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run the loop from 1 to less or equal a value. Your code is equal to:

```
for ( i = 0; i < (n – 2); i++)
  for (j = i; j < (n – 1); j ++)
    for (k = j; k < n; k++)
      Print “Hello World”;
```

So your inner loop runs `n-j`, the middle one multiplies it with `n-1-i` and the outer one multiplies it with `n-2`. So you get `(n-j)*(n-1-i)*(n-2)`. `n` has `O(n)` complexity. Because of `i` runs from `0` to `(n-1)`, you could replace it with `O(n)` (because sum(0, n) = 0 + 1 + .. + N = 0.5 * n^2 = O(n^2)). It is the same with `j`. So you get `(O(n)-O(n))*(O(n)-1-O(n))*(O(n)-2) = O(n)*(n)*O(n) = O(n^3)`.

For details why you could replace `i` with `O(n)` see "Nested loops" at [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html).

Comment: thank you for the article. it cleared up a lot of things for me.